# Custom category attributes

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm trying to have a `multiselect` option in my magento backend categories.

I have the following code:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array( 
        'group' => "General Information", // and this one 
        'label'  => 'Location', 
        'type' => 'varchar', 
        'input' => 'multiselect', 
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE, 
        'visible' => true, 
        'required' => false, 
        'is_user_defined' => true, 
        'option'=> array (
                'value' => array(
                        'england'=> array( 
                        0 =>'England'),
                        'scotland'=> array( 
                        0 =>'Scotland')
                        )
                )
    );

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'bottom_description', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

This creates a new attribute in the backend, but there are no values.

Do I need to configure anything else so I can see these values?

Thanks

EDIT:

In config.xml I have:

```
<version>0.8.0</version>
```

I have another file:

`mysql4-upgrade-0.7.0-0.8.0.php`

This file doesn't seem to get run when I clear the cache and visit the categories.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you write above script in mysql4-upgrade script right? have you update config.xml version
because it execute only if version is upgraded in config.xml
so please check it

Comment: Yes. Everytime I run the above, I increase the version `0.4.0`, `0.5.0` etc and rename the file `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.4.0.php`, `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.5.0.php` to match. But still get no values after clearing cache

Comment: version should updated for example
upgrade-0.0.1-0.4.0.php to mysql4-upgrade-0.4.0-0.5.0.php

Comment: Ah, that could be the problem then. It isn't picking up any changes I've been making

Comment: check the "core_resource" table find your <module>_setup entry & check the current version

Comment: Current version is `0.8.0`

Comment: so now your upgradable file should be
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.0-0.9.0.php & also change config.xml to 0.9.0

Comment: and if you want to upgrade don't rename it create new file with upgradeable version

Comment: check this link http://www.danneh.org/2010/03/adding-multi-select-attributes-using-an-installer-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

Arrr....you were close. Instead of `'value' => array(....)` it should be, `'values' => array(...)`.
But I see a problem here. When adding options to attributes the option value should be int values.
Let's say you add the attribute as in your code and save a product with `Location` `England,Scotland`. The value in the data base is not going to be `england,scotland` Is going to be something like: `76,77`. The autogenerated Ids for the options Scotland and England. If you want to have the values saved as `england,scotland` you need to write a custom source model for this attribute.
[You can find here an example and adapt it to your needs.](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

For adding the custom yes/no attribute in the category section please create the module and enter the following code.

```html
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'featured_product', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Featured Category',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
));?>
```

Please refer my tutorial as well.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-add-custom-attribute-dropdown-to-category-section-magento/